# Element type invalid within React project - Import issue?

Tags: reactjs

Within my React application, I'm met with an issue which seems to be related to imports or extending Component | React.Component with my main App class.
The error I'm met with is:

> Element type is invalid: expected a string (for built-in components)
> or a class/function (for composite components) but got: undefined.

I assumed it might have to do with default vs named import of Component, but even when using React.Component instead of Component, I'm met with this issue.

Is there any reason why this would occur?
The import statements I've used are structure as such, below:

```
import React from 'react';
import Component from 'react';
import './App.css';
import Exercises from "./components/ExerciseDay";
import MySurvey from "./components/MySurvey";
import ExerciseSelector from "./components/ExerciseSelector";
import ToggleDisplay from 'react-toggle-display';

export default class App extends React.Component {
    render() {
        const surveyCompleted = localStorage.getItem("experience");
        return (
            <div className="App">
                <header className="App-header">
                    <h1 className="App-title" style={{fontFamily: "Comfortaa, cursive", fontSize: 35}}>
                        Sheiko Workout Finder
                    </h1>
                </header>
                <ToggleDisplay show={!surveyCompleted} tag="section">
                    <MySurvey/>
                </ToggleDisplay>
                <ToggleDisplay show={surveyCompleted !== null}>
                    <ExerciseSelector/>
                    <Exercises/>
                </ToggleDisplay>
                <footer style={{fontFamily: "Comfortaa, cursive", fontSize: 20}}>
                    <p>
                        Note here -&nbsp;
                    </p>
                </footer>
            </div>
        );
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

A Component is named export. Instead of `import Component from 'react';`

it should be `import { Component } from 'react'; //with curly braces`
But you are not using it. It can be deleted because you are using `React.Component`.
Most likely there is another problem because there is not shown how you are exporting other components from other files ( ExerciseDay,MySurvey,ExerciseSelector ) they or something from them might be **named export** instead of **default export**. Check how you are exporting them

And there is another case that will cause this error. If you are importing something wrong also in these components. For example, something imported in **ExerciseDay** from another file is incorrect. Like exported as **named export** instead of **default export** or vice versa